# Spring scheduler is not starting

Tags: java, spring

I have created a spring scheduler in maven project but its not starting. Its in separate maven module. When i call myScheduleTask() method from somewhere in project then its starting after that but i need to run it independently without calling. is there anything missing in it. Below is scheduler class i am trying.

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void myScheduleTask(){
     system.out.println("Scheduler started");
}

}
```

Comment: Did you add @EnableScheduling ??

Comment: Yes its added to appConfig.java class in different module. appConfig.java class also having @ComponentScan(basePackage = {com.schedule.*}). Do i need to add it to scheduler class as well?

Comment: @Borsuk annotation EnableScheduling not working for me